# Delaying JOptionPane with Web-Browser

Tags: java

Wondering how to delay a JOptionPane. The goal is to get the picture to pop up, then the box, so that the box will always open infront of the default browser.

Code

```
            //this is with the bottom thing, probably above the modules
            public void openWebPage(String url){
                   try {         
                     java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
                   }
                   catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                   }
                }

            private void ResetButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

                openWebPage("http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg");

                 //int delay = 1000; //milliseconds [Unused]

                String message = "I didn't know how to code a reset button." + "\n";
                String message2 = "So have a nice cat instead. -Cakemoth";


                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message + message2, "Class Registration", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                // URL : http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to display the image in a browser?

Just display the image in a JLabel and add the label to a frame. Then you are in full control of the application.

You can use `ImageIO` to read an image from a URL:

```
BufferedImage image = Imagio.read(...);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon( image );
JLabel label = new JLabel( icon );
frame.add( label );
frame.setVisible( true );

// show JOptionPane
```

Comment: New to java, trying to learn, have not gotten into the realm of Images yet.

Comment: @Exxane, `have not gotten into the realm of Images yet.` - not sure what that means. Displaying an image on a label is far easier then trying to use the desktop class. Start with the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for working examples. Keep a link to the tutorial handy for all Swing basics.